# xmlhttp.open while onMouseOver for specific ID

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to shorten down my code a bit, I have roughly 36 separate text files that are individually opened and displayed on the page when the mouse hovers over a link and then opens a website when the link is clicked on.

```
function openLink1() {
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // code for older browsers
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =
      xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "file.txt", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I am trying to figure a loop or if/else statement but I am a javascript noob. Is there a way for me to be able to set this up so that I don't need to have 30+ of these functions here? I was thinking of setting up an ID on each link and then do a statement which would change the "file.txt" depending on the ID?

Comment: Just change the function to be `function openLink(fileName)` and do `xmlhttp.open('GET', fileName, true);`  and when you invoke the function pass the name of the file you want to open...

Comment: Thank you for the response! So I can pass the fileName over from each of the links `<a onmouseover="openLink()" onClick="openWeb()" class="linker">epsilon</a>` where in this should I define what `fileName` should be?

Comment: You do `<a onmouseover="openLink('file1.txt')" onClick="openWeb()" class="linker">epsilon</a>`

Comment: Ok great, I tried this but I didn't include any quotations. I'm buying a book tomorrow hahah. Thank you very much